# What is the reason to add Local Maven Repository to sbt?

Tags: sbt

I keep seeing sbt projects with the following `resolvers` setting in their build definition:

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
```

It's also described in [the official documentation of sbt in Resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#resolvers) section.

My limited knowledge of using sbt and build management tools in general lets me however consider it as a kind of **anti-pattern**.

The reason is that if a project declares a dependency on a library in the Local Maven Repository it somehow got downloaded there in the first place so it's available somewhere outside the local maven repository. If it is, why not using the original repository as the source?

If the dependency is not in a public repository, and is a dependency of a project, the project can use `dependsOn` to declare it without the additional repository in `resolvers`.

Please advice as I may be missing something obvious that makes the `resolvers` setting indispensable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious reason would be if one of your dependencies is a local project built with maven.

One scenario:

1. You have a project x which you build with sbt
2. X depends on y. Y is built with maven.
3. There is a bug in y which you need to fix/test, and you want to regression test x before you check it in.
4. You build a snapshot of y, and then you can test x before you commit the change to y.

Comment: *Built with maven* or any non-sbt build tool before publishing it to an official repository from which the sbt project could pull it down. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I've been thinking about the answer and came up with another question - why for such a simple, temporary change, the `resolvers` setting should not be changed in a global configuration? Why would that be part of the project's `build.sbt`? It'd be a temporary change to `build.sbt` without committing it to the scm repository.